# Wordpress Plugin: Oauth2 redirect

Tags: oauth

I'm new to WP plugin dev, and have a task of writing a WordPress plugin. It is a basic form of plugin that would receive user input, check for validity and if valid submit to an external API to that WP site. Now every submission should go with a token, which means on admin panel, user should get the token with OAuth2 to the API app. That brings me to the question.

I have admin page set, and there I press a link taking me to Oauth2 site, user get authenticated. Now it is time to redirect to my WP site: How do I set URL Oauth2 site have to redirect to, so that I can extract query strings and request for access token?

Google didn't help much, may be because I'm not using valid keywords in searching.

Comment: Typically you provide a redirect URL to the OAuth provider and it’s the provider’s responsibility to redirect the user back to your site. So the answer depends on the exact provider. You’ll need to consult its documentation for the exact answer.

Comment: I know that. My question was what is the best route to WP site should I use and how do I get the `$_GET` results from the plugin to ask for access token. Sorry if my question misled you instead